# Is Li-Po battery safe to bring in flight

Tags: lipo

I am going to bring my device with me on flight, and I have this battery : https://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/lithium-polymer-battery-1000mah.html

installed within the device.

I am wondering if this battery is safe for flight? Should I bring it with me in carry-on luggage or I can put the device in checked in luggage?

Comment: I suggest you read [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42411/are-battery-packs-allowed-in-hand-luggage) on safety regulations regarding li-ion batteries.

Comment: Answered on another SE site: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/58057/44454

Comment: Essentially: the battery is regarded as somewhat dangerous by the airlines. You must keep it in your carry-on luggage, generally.

Comment: Here's a great question regarding what can go wrong with Li-Pos: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230155/why-is-there-so-much-fear-surrounding-lipo-batteries ; generally though, flying with *raw* cells (no safety circuit) is far, far more dangerous than with an actual battery (incl. safety circuit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer would be:

- **yes** Li-ion batteries are generally safe for flight conditions. Usually, you are required to keep them in hand luggage.
- whenever a battery is safe **in your device** cannot be realistically answered without knowing what device that is. If your device is DIY, you may have less trouble at security check if you carry the battery separately.
- there are limits on the amount of Lithium you can carry on a flight. These limits may vary depending on the airline and country of destination. 1000mAh (3.7Wh) is well within such limits, but if you have lots of other devices with batteries (laptop, mobile phone etc.) it may be worth it to do the math.

I have asked a [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59110/diy-computer-in-hand-luggage-what-to-expect-on-security-checks) on Travel.SE. The bottom line was that as long as your device doesn't look like "Realistic Replicas of Explosives", you should be allowed to travel with it, but you can't be 100% sure.