# Replacing a Lipo phone battery with a li-ion battery

Tags: batteries

Is it okay to replace my worn li-polymer 3.8v and 2200maH battery with a li-ion battery with 3.7v and same 2200maH capacity?Will the 0.1v be of any harm to the delicate electronics of the phone?

Comment: how are you planning to charge the battery?

Comment: Don't. Charging and thresholds are different for those chemistries.

Comment: Your battery might explode

Comment: 0.1 V no problem and 3.6V float charger is ok too if all you want is a cheap non Mobile solution

Comment: Repair questions are off-topic here.  And even if they were not, this is unanswerable because the voltages you quote or the nominal voltages, not the charge cutoff voltages.  Such a lack of information about how the actual design works is why repair questions are considered off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Charging voltage for the newer Li-Po cells is usually 4.35 V. When you use an older Li-Ion cells in modern phone, the battery standard charge level of 4.20V will be exceeded substanially. It might be OK to charge a 4.2V battery with 4.35 V levels, but battery cycle life will be decreased about 3-4-fold, as [this example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/317798/117785) shows.

But before worry about all this, check the actual charging voltage on your phone, maybe it is just 4.2 V standard.

Comment: With all the questions regarding battery swapping  Do you know if there is a reference question that could be a generic answer to most common questions (safety, charging caracteristics, etc...)?

Comment: 4.35 V is LiFePO₄ (aka lithium iron phosphate). LiPo is lithium-polymer, which is just a way of manufacturing the cell; there's nothing special about its chemistry. It's 4.2 V just like standard non-polymer li-ions.