# Wiring this 2-cell battery controller to 1-output psu?

Tags: batteries, charger

I need to take the controller board from a 2-cell battery (2 x 3.7v) to a single power supply (1 x 7.4v).  The board has 3 wires, "B+", "B-" and "BC". The two cells are wired in series to "B+" & "B-" and the piece of wire that acts as a bridge, is also directly connected to "BC".

So, I'm guessing B+- is getting 7.4v and BC is getting 3.7v.
**Now that I only have one 7.4v output in my Psu**, I'm not sure how to wire this. I've tested the following:

- PSU+ to "B+" in board, PSU- to "B-" in board *Did not work*
- PSU+ to "B+" in board, PSU- to "BC" in board *Did not work*
- PSU- to "B-" in board, PSU+ to "BC" in board *Did not work*

As that was not successful I'm wondering If I can replicate the 2-cell setup just with one . I mean, getting a 7.4v output to B+- and another 3.7v positive wired to BC. Is that possible? I'm very lost at this.

Thank you so much.

*Note: Why would I want to use that controller board if I have a Psu? Well, the device I want to power has to recognise a propietary power source via an ID chip wich this board has.*

[image: Diagram]

Comment: You do not have one 7.4V cell. You have one case with two 3.7V cells internally connected in series. If you can't get that internal connection out ... I don't think you can use that controller.

Comment: If you have a 2S lithium battery without a "center tap", you shouldn't use that battery at all. Lithium batteries need to be balanced.

Comment: My new 7.4 cell is not exactly a cell (I explained it that way for simplicity). Let say it's a one-output 7.4v psu.

Comment: The Li pack is indeed a 2-cell pack and i also agree that Li cells should be balanced. But fact here is that this IS a 2-pack cell without mid connection brought out. You could try to make a voltage divider between B+ and B- and connect half  pack voltage to BC.

Comment: To be complete: make that a high impedance voltage divider. Not suer if it will work though.

Answer (score 0):

Proper comment as a semi-answer.

In contrast to my previous comments. While you **could** try to make a virtual mid connection, its strongly reccomended to **not** try this. It's dangerous if it would work.

This **is** a 2-cell pack. If indeed it does not bring out the mid-connection, you should not charge nor discharge it.

Please read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230155/why-is-there-so-much-fear-surrounding-lipo-batteries%20'this%22) question and answer.

Comment: My new 7.4 cell is not exactly a cell (I explained it that way for simplicity). Let say it's a one-output 7.4v psu. There's nothing to charge actually, but I need to use this board between my Psu and my device because the device has to recognice a valid power input to work (It has a kind of ID chip).

Comment: in that case you can safely try to make the virtual midpoint. But that module will still protect against max charge and discharge current, balancing and over- and undervoltage.