# Can I charge a Li-ion cell with high voltage until reaching the nominal one?

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, charging

I have one 18650 cell which has a nominal voltage of 3.1 V in the specs. Right now, it is discharged and reads 2.8V. I was wondering if I can charge it directly with a panel solar (18V) until it reaches 3.2V and then disconnect it. A higher voltage difference means a higher current, right? My solar panel can deliver max 0.5 A in theory and the cell can be charged with 1C (2.6 A) so I am not worried that the current is too high, but what about the voltage difference? What can happen if I charge it with higher voltage?

Comment: What does the data sheet say?

Comment: Why would you think it is sensible to charge a 3.1V cell with 18V ?

Comment: Well, they recommend CC/CV. So constant current until the voltage has reached the highest value, then keep voltage constant.

Comment: After reading this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230155/why-is-there-so-much-fear-surrounding-lipo-batteries and watching the videos I have decided not to develop my own circuits. I have bought a USB Li-Ion charger at the same time as the lipo cells.

Comment: &Physther So, with that logic why not just use the mains at 230V just rectify it ? Don’t try ...

Comment: I asked a question because I wasn't sure. Please correct my logic if it is wrong and/or if you wish to. Otherwise we can go in chat and do this kind of game.