# Why don't Li-pol accumulators change the polarity of an electromagnet?

Tags: batteries, electromagnetism, magnet, electromagnet

I made a simple electromagnet with a screw and a wire.

When I supply power to it via 1 AA battery (1.5v) and change + and - contacts it acts differently with other magnets (attracts and repels), but when I supply power via my 250mAh, 3.7V Li-pol accumulator, it only attracts other magnets, even if I change the contacts' polarity.

Can I make my electromagnet repel other magnets with Li-pol accumulators supply?

Comment: DC is DC; if you reverse the polarity, the rotational sense of the magnetic field reverses. That's a fundamental truth of physics; it very literally is what causes light to exist. I trust that truth 100%. I don't trust you to not have mixed up your magnets, or your contacts, sorry :(

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment, I will make another test tomorrow. Maybe I'm really messed up with contacts.

Comment: Sorry, what is a li-pol accumulator?

Comment: In some countries across the pond, they translate a Li-PO battery into Li-pol and translate a rechargeable battery into accumulator.

Comment: `it only attracts other magnets` ... remove power ... it will still attract magnets

Comment: @audioguru correct

Comment: @jsolota I think screw driver do not have electromagnetic fields without power and wiring, but still can be attracted by magnets

Answer (score 3):

A few turns of wire around a screw would short out a battery like this. What's happening is that the Li-po is shutting off using its internal protection circuit.

Let's compare the two batteries when we connect a nearly dead-short load, like your 'few turns':

- AA battery: battery internal resistance limits the current, energizes the magnet
- Li-po battery: **protection circuit detects a short**, cuts off the battery, magnet does not energize

Non-energized electro magnet will still attract magnets, but won’t repel them.

Why does the Li-po have a protection circuit? Li-po and Li-ion batteries have very low internal resistance. Without protection, **when shorted they will heat up very quickly and even catch fire.**

Fortunately for you the protection circuit did its job, and you only had a non-functional magnet vs. a [fiery YouTube-worthy disaster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hg3r2erRrfw).

In future, **never** connect a dead short across Li-po or Li-ion battery. Add a series resistance to limit the current.

Related: [Why is there so much fear surrounding LiPo batteries?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230155/why-is-there-so-much-fear-surrounding-lipo-batteries)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Here is a video of what I finally succed to do with AA battery. https://youtu.be/ScmpNUSmIjw First time I thought that the reason was that the coil wiring was uneven on a screw driver and it messed up the electromagnetic fields, but your explanation looks more reasonable.